# static property with non-static List<T>

Tags: c#, static

A Static property returns a List with generated Simulation Data. 
In this example I create IPAddress from strings to simulate IPs from a mobile device.
What are the risc of memory leaks?

```
    static readonly string[] IPv6Simu = { "fe80::3a6d:eeeb:8bff:4ef2", "fc01:abab:cdcd:efe0:49d2:473:579c:cfaa" };
    static readonly string[] IPv4Simu = { "172.22.1.100", "172.22.1.100" };
    static readonly string[] InterfaceName = { "mnet1", "mnet0" };

   public static List<IpData> StaticSimulateIPFactory
    { get
        {
            List<IpData> simu = new List<IpData>();
            try
            {
                IPAddress ip;
                foreach (var IPv6 in IPv6Simu)
                {
                    if (IPAddress.TryParse(IPv6, out ip))
                    {
                        simu.Add(new IpData() { InterfaceName = InterfaceName.FirstOrDefault(), IPAddress = ip });
                    }
                }
                foreach (var IPv4 in IPv4Simu)
                {
                    if (IPAddress.TryParse(IPv4, out ip))
                    {
                        simu.Add(new IpData() { InterfaceName = InterfaceName.FirstOrDefault(), IPAddress = ip });
                    }
                } 
                return simu;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                simu.Add(new IpData() { InterfaceName = "INV", IPAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[]{127,0,0,1} )});
                return simu;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you *expect* memory-leaks? If you know this you know what to dispose in order to prevent those.

Answer (score 0):

Your property is static, which means you can access it without an instance of the class. It does not mean that there is some implicit data, that is persistent within the class.

In the body you create a new `List` in every call. Those objects will be returned to callers and garbage collected when they stop using them. There is no risk of memory leaks with the snippet you provided alone.

Answer (score 0):

[Memory Leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) per se are parts in your code, that consume memory, but don't release them after consumtion. 
e.g: If you create a global Object that holds references on  large objects, which don't implement IDisposable, the GC can't free the memory. Under some circumstances even if the programm has ended, the memory is still "in use".

After reboot, the RAM is cleared, so the memory is not longer used.
In your case, the list is so small and the objects are so tiny, I don't think that there will be a Memory leak